# Need Help Moving Onclick Event To External Javascript To Comply With Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, getelementbyid, content-security-policy

I've moved my inline scripts to external pages to comply with Content Security Policy.  This is the last CSP issue I need to resolve.  I need help replacing "onclick" from two buttons with an event listener.  I've researched thoroughly, but the examples differ enough from my code that I'm having difficulty figuring it out.  I am very new to Javascript.  I have two toggle tabs that reveal pricing when clicked.  The first Tab is open by default when page loads.  When I remove "onclick" from button and add the event listener to my JS file, the tabs will no longer open when clicked and the default open also does not work.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I would appreciate assistance formatting the Javascript within my external page to make these toggle tabs work with CSP.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="tab">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/myExternalJavascript.js">
  </script>
  <button 
   class="tablinks"
   onclick="openTerms(event, 'Weekly')" 
   id="button1">Click This
  </button>
  <button 
   class="tablinks"
   onclick="openTerms(event, 'Monthly')" 
   id="button2">Click This
  </button>
</div>
<div id="Weekly" class="tabcontent">Do something great.</div>
<div id="Monthly" class="tabcontent">Do something great.</div>
```

Here is what's inside my external js file (using javascript from w3 tabs):

```
// Get the element with id="button1" and click on it
document.getElementById("button1").click();

function openTerms(evt, priceTerms){
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++){
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(priceTerms).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', function(){
  openTerms(event, 'Weekly')
});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener('click', function(){
  openTerms(event, 'Monthly')
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Move your script reference to just before the close of the `body` element so that by the time your script attempts to search through the document for elements, all the elements have been parsed into memory.**

That should solve your issue so that, this:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTerms(event, 'Weekly')" 
id="button1">Click This</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTerms(event, 'Monthly')" 
id="button2">Click This</button>
```

Gets the `onclick="...."` part removed and in your JavaScript, and then you add:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){openTerms(event, 'Weekly')});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(){openTerms(event, 'Monthly')});
```

Comment: I would also suggest putting the configuration into window.onload = function() { ... code goes here ...} This will further help avoid trying to run scripts against elements that have not been loaded into the page.

Comment: @daddygames You *could* do that, but moving the script to the end of the file is commonplace and removes the need for that. Doing both is overkill. Also, don't use `window.onload = callback`, use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback)`

Comment: Could you clarify with a reference as to why you would use an event listener instead of the window.onload event? My suggestion is additive to your answer. It's not necessary, but good to make a habit of doing it this way.

Comment: @daddygames It's not a good habit to do both, it's overkill. The location of the script solves the problem. As for `.addEventListener()` vs. `.onload`, you can't register two or more callbacks with `.onload`, but you can with `.addEventListener` (which is the modern standard for event binding).

Comment: @daddygames There are a million things that you *can* still do in JavaScript, but using event properties is just as much of an out-of-date practice that doesn't promote modern standards use and scalability as inline event attributes.

Comment: I could argue the same against using simple script placement. You can add other callbacks using event listeners if you want, even if you already use window.onload. I don't see any reason why you believe that's a modern vs antiquated method of programming. You will need a quality reference to prove that difference to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166057/discussion-between-scott-marcus-and-daddygames).

Comment: Another way of doing this would be to move the "Weekly" and "Monthly" strings to `data-` attributes and bind a single event handler to all buttons with the class "tablinks".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, but that's not what the question was about.

Comment: The suggestion by Scott Marcus worked.  The buttons or tabs are functioning properly now.  However, the following does not work after I remove onclick from the button html.  Any suggestions?      
    document.getElementById("button1").click();

Comment: @S.Jones You don't really need to activate the `click` of the button, just call the function that the click calls: `function(){openTerms(event, 'Weekly')}`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Would you please clarify where I should place your code example within the external javascript?   I've tried various combinations with no success.

Comment: @S.Jones It's not about where, in the external script, the javascript code should go. The external script reference itself (`<script src=....>`), needs to be placed just prior to the closing `body` tag (`</body>`) in the HTML document.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The external script reference is placed just prior to the closing body tag.  The first code example you offered works well and tabs function properly.  If I place the suggested function that the click calls anywhere within the external sheet, the tabs no longer function and the first tab will not display on page load.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Could the suggested function be a conflict with the following from my external sheet:     function openTerms(evt, priceTerms) { var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; } tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");} document.getElementById(priceTerms).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";}

Answer (score 1):

Placing the following at the very bottom of the external sheet solved the issue and button1's content now displays on page load:

```
document.getElementById("button1").click();
```

Placement within the external sheet seemed to be the issue.  The following placement solved the problem.

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){openTerms(event, 'Weekly')});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(){openTerms(event, 'Monthly')});
document.getElementById("button1").click();
```

Comment: Simple solution that works. If you are using flask, just add <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='main.js')}}"></script> to the bottom below the </body> tag and then put in your code in that js doc . +1